# Spark 2.3.1 Structured Streaming Input Rate

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I wonder if there is a way to specify the size of the mini-batch in Spark Structured streaming. That is rather than only stating the mini-batch interval (Triggers), I would like to state how many Row can be in a mini-batch (DataFrame) per interval. 
Is there a way to do that ?

Aside from the general capability to do that, I particularily need to apply that in testing scenario, where i have an MemoryStream. I would like Spark to consume a certain amount of data from the MemoryStream, instead of taking all of it at once, to actually see how the the overall application behave. My understanding is that the MemoryStream data structure needs to be filled before launching the job on it. Hence, how can i see the mini-batch processing behavior, is spark is able to ingest the entire content of the MemoryStream within the interval that I give ?

**EDIT1**

In the Kafka Integration I have found the following:

> **maxOffsetsPerTrigger**: Rate limit on maximum number of offsets processed per trigger interval. The specified total number of offsets will be proportionally split across topicPartitions of different volume.

But that is just for KAFKA integration. I have also seen

> **maxFilesPerTrigger**: maximum number of new files to be considered in every trigger

So it seems things are defined per source types. Hence, is there a way to control how data is consumed from MEMORYSTREAM[ROW] ?

Answer (score 0):

Look for below guys they can  solve your problem:

```
 1.spark.streaming.backpressure.initialRate 
 2.spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled
```

Comment: Just to be clear because that is something that confuses me. My understanding is that Spark Structured streaming is build on top of Spark SQL and not Spark Streaming. NoneTheless would you say that things that properties that applies to Spark Streaming also Apply to Spark Structured Streaming ? Maybe I should create a separated question for that  ?

Comment: Does this not only apply to spark streaming and not spark structured streaming ?